# getPositiveValues won't return the values

Tags: c

#### What is not working:

In the code below, the values input in `scanf` under `getPositiveValue` will not return.  They return as `0` no matter what the input is.

I have no clue how to get around this. Can someone show me why it is not working?

#### What I have tried:

I tried using `return CHAN;` and even `return CHAN.n;` and all the other members but that did not work.

#### My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define N 25 //number of lines

typedef struct CHANNEL_ //Structure CHANNEL
{
    char name[9];
    double n;//roughness coefficient
    double S;//channel slope
    double B;//width
    double D;//maxDepth
} CHANNEL;

double computeVelocity(CHANNEL, double);

int main(void)
{
    CHANNEL CHAN;
    void getPositiveValue(CHANNEL);
    void displayTable(CHANNEL);
    //Function declarations

    printf("Enter the name of the channel: ");
    fgets(CHAN.name, 9, stdin);
    getPositiveValue(CHAN);
    printf("Channel data for %s\n Coefficient of roughness: %lf\n Slope: %lf\n Width: %lf\n Maximum depth: %lf\n", CHAN.name, CHAN.n, CHAN.S, CHAN.B, CHAN.D);
    printf("Depth    Average Velocity\n");
    displayTable(CHAN); //function call to display the table with values
}

void getPositiveValue(CHANNEL CHAN)
{
    int Flag; //sentinel
    do
    {
        Flag = FALSE;
        printf("Give the coefficient for roughness, slope, width, and maxdepth: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", &CHAN.n, &CHAN.S, &CHAN.B, &CHAN.D);
        if(CHAN.n < 0 || CHAN.S < 0 || CHAN.B < 0 || CHAN.D < 0) //sentinel checkpoint
        {
            Flag = TRUE;
            printf("The values must be positive.\n");
        }
    } while(Flag == TRUE);
}

void displayTable(CHANNEL CHAN)
{
    double increment = CHAN.D/N;
    double H = 0; //depth
    double arraydepth[N]; //N is used to avoid magic numbers when defining array size
    double arrayvelocity[N]; //N is used to avoid magic numbers when defining array size
    int i; //using separate integers for the two different arrays just so it looks better and less confusing
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        H += increment;
        arrayvelocity[i] = computeVelocity(CHAN, H);
        arraydepth[i] = H;
        printf("%lf %lf\n", arraydepth[i], arrayvelocity[i]);
    }
}

double computeVelocity(CHANNEL CHAN, double H)
{
    double U;
    U = CHAN.B / H;
    U = U / (CHAN.B + (2 * H));
    U = pow(U, (2 / 3));
    U = U / CHAN.n;
    U = U * (sqrt(CHAN.S));

    return U;
}
```

Comment: There must be a semicolon at the end of `void computeVelocity(CHANNEL, double)`.

Comment: @DYZ That only created a warning and the error stayed.

Comment: You have another error, as explained by Chris Mc.

Comment: @DYZ -- the explanation is incorrect since C maintains separate name spaces for tags and ordinary identifiers.

Comment: Is there a way to bump this to get further help?, CS Pei has helped with the errors but for some reason the values won't return when put in scanf in the getPositiveValue function

Comment: @GuyBean -- if you are having problems with input, that seems beyond the scope of your original question (which seems to be about fixing compile time errors). I would suggest posting a new question, with examples of input, expected output, and actual output (or a description of actual code behavior). It is considered bad etiquette on SO to change the substance of a question after answers have arrived.

Comment: @DavidBowling I'm limited to one question sadly, and this is really urgent. This is my output http://prntscr.com/l64qrx the expected output is http://prntscr.com/l64qvz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input problem you are having is because of the fact that functions are call by value in C. This means that when you pass a `struct` to a function, it is a *copy* of the `struct` that is worked with in the function, not the original. Any changes made to the `struct` within the `getPositiveValue()` function are not visible once control returns to `main()`.

To fix this problem, pass a pointer to the structure. Use the `->` operator to dereference the pointer and access members in one shot. Here is a modified version of your code. I also took the liberty of moving your function declarations to the top of the program.

There is also an error in the call to the `pow()` function found in `computeVelocity()`:

```
U = pow(U, (2 / 3));
```

should be:

```
U = pow(U, (2.0 / 3.0));
```

The expression `2 / 3` performs integer division, with the result zero, so after this call to `pow()`, `U` is always 1. This can be easily fixed by forcing floating point division, as in the second line above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define N 25 //number of lines

typedef struct CHANNEL_ //Structure CHANNEL
{
    char name[9];
    double n;//roughness coefficient
    double S;//channel slope
    double B;//width
    double D;//maxDepth
} CHANNEL;

double computeVelocity(CHANNEL, double);
void getPositiveValue(CHANNEL *);
void displayTable(CHANNEL);

int main(void)
{
    CHANNEL CHAN;
    printf("Enter the name of the channel: ");
    fgets(CHAN.name, 9, stdin);
    getPositiveValue(&CHAN);
    printf("Channel data for %s\n Coefficient of roughness: %lf\n Slope: %lf\n Width: %lf\n Maximum depth: %lf\n", CHAN.name, CHAN.n, CHAN.S, CHAN.B, CHAN.D);
    printf("Depth    Average Velocity\n");
    displayTable(CHAN); //function call to display the table with values
}

void getPositiveValue(CHANNEL *CHAN)
{
    int Flag; //sentinel
    do
    {
        Flag = FALSE;
        printf("Give the coefficient for roughness, slope, width, and maxdepth: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", &CHAN->n, &CHAN->S, &CHAN->B, &CHAN->D);
        if(CHAN->n < 0 || CHAN->S < 0 || CHAN->B < 0 || CHAN->D < 0) //sentinel checkpoint
        {
            Flag = TRUE;
            printf("The values must be positive.\n");
        }
    }while(Flag == TRUE);
}

void displayTable(CHANNEL CHAN)
{
    double increment = CHAN.D/N;
    double H = 0; //depth
    double arraydepth[N]; //N is used to avoid magic numbers when defining array size
    double arrayvelocity[N]; //N is used to avoid magic numbers when defining array size
    int i; //using separate integers for the two different arrays just so it looks better and less confusing
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        H += increment;
        arrayvelocity[i] = computeVelocity(CHAN, H);
        arraydepth[i] = H;
        printf("%lf %lf\n", arraydepth[i], arrayvelocity[i]);
    }
}

double computeVelocity(CHANNEL CHAN, double H)
{
    double U;
    U = CHAN.B / H;
    U = U / (CHAN.B + (2 * H));
    U = pow(U, (2.0 / 3.0));
    U = U / CHAN.n;
    U = U * (sqrt(CHAN.S));
    return U;
}
```

Sample program interaction:

```
Enter the name of the channel: chan
Give the coefficient for roughness, slope, width, and maxdepth: 0.035 0.0001 10 4.2
Channel data for chan

 Coefficient of roughness: 0.035000
 Slope: 0.000100
 Width: 10.000000
 Maximum depth: 4.200000
Depth    Average Velocity
0.168000 0.917961
0.336000 0.566077
0.504000 0.423161
0.672000 0.342380
0.840000 0.289368
1.008000 0.251450
1.176000 0.222759
1.344000 0.200172
1.512000 0.181859
1.680000 0.166669
1.848000 0.153840
2.016000 0.142843
2.184000 0.133301
2.352000 0.124935
2.520000 0.117535
2.688000 0.110939
2.856000 0.105020
3.024000 0.099677
3.192000 0.094829
3.360000 0.090410
3.528000 0.086363
3.696000 0.082644
3.864000 0.079214
4.032000 0.076040
4.200000 0.073095
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many compiler error in your code. Here is my first try to fix it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define N 25 //number of lines

typedef struct CHANNEL_ {
    char name[50];
    double n;//roughness coefficient
    double S;//channel slope
    double B;//width
    double D;//maxDepth
} CHANNEL;

double computeVelocity(CHANNEL, double);
void getPositiveValue(CHANNEL);
void displayTable(CHANNEL);

int main(void) {
    CHANNEL CHAN;

    printf("Enter the name of the channel: ");
    fgets(CHAN.name, 50, stdin);
    getPositiveValue(CHAN);
    printf("Channel data for %s\n Coefficient of roughness: %lf\n Slope: %lf\n Width: %lf\n Maximum depth: %lf\n", CHAN.name, CHAN.n, CHAN.S, CHAN.B, CHAN.D);
    printf("Depth    Average Velocity\n");
    displayTable(CHAN); //function call to display the table with values
}

void getPositiveValue(CHANNEL CHAN) {
    int Flag; //sentinel
    do {
        Flag = FALSE;
        printf("Give the coefficient for roughness: \n Give the slope: \n Give the channel width: \n Give the maximum depth of the channel: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", &CHAN.n, &CHAN.S, &CHAN.B, &CHAN.D);
        if(CHAN.n < 0 || CHAN.S < 0 || CHAN.B < 0 || CHAN.D < 0) {
            Flag = TRUE;
            printf("The values must be positive.\n");
        }
    } while(Flag == TRUE);
}

void displayTable(CHANNEL CHAN) {
    double increment = CHAN.D/N;
    double H = 0; //depth
    double arraydepth[N];
    double arrayvelocity[N];
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        H += increment;
        arrayvelocity[i] = computeVelocity(CHAN, H);
        arraydepth[i] = H;
        printf("%lf %lf\n", arraydepth[i], arrayvelocity[i]);
    }
}

double computeVelocity(CHANNEL CHAN, double H)
{
    double U;
    U = CHAN.B / H;
    U = U / (CHAN.B + (2 * H));
    U = pow(U, (2 / 3));
    U = U / CHAN.n;
    U = U * (sqrt(CHAN.S));

    return U;
}
```

The first error would be `struct` definition. In C, you can define the `struct` and at the same time define a variable. But you should not use the same name to confuse yourself and the compiler. Also you need to understand `void` function does not return a value and cannot be on the right side of an `=` expression.

Use `typedef` can save you to type `struct` keyword each time you need it. You also need to use `%s` to output a string. Also typos here and there.

Comment: I tried applying your changes, sadly the same errors remain :(

Comment: you did not copied the whole program, did you? what compiler you use? it passed on my Linux box with gcc 7.0

Comment: Yes, thank you. Void was my problem having it on computeVelocity. This fixed my errors. big thanks!! I'm using GCC compiler also.

Comment: Do you have any idea as to why the scanf in getPositiveValue doesn't return the values?